# can a capacity *collapse*?

Tags: word-usage

If a capacity ceases to exist due to a sudden change, would it be appropriate to talk about "a collapsed capacity", or "the collapse of their capacity"?

Later edits:

1. I mean capacity in the sense of 'capability'.
2. If this phrasing sounds odd, which word could possibly deliver the idea of an abrupt deterioration in one's capacity to do something?

Comment: What do you mean by *capacity*? A volume, or a capability, or an office/position?

Comment: A capability. Sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: I don't see anything unusual in usages such as [*While the intelligence obtained from the Pacific and Southeast Asia revealed promising signs that prolonged setbacks had worn down the Japanese soldier's morale, a continued weakening was unlikely to lead to **a collapse in their capacity** to fight, at least in the foreseeable future*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=abx_AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA159&dq=%22collapse+in+their+capacity%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22collapse%20in%20their%20capacity%22&f=false). If anyone disagrees, that's just a matter of opinion.

Comment: Pretty much anything that can be regarded as having some volume or substance can "collapse".  However, it's a little questionable whether it's the best word to use when referring to the capabilities of an individual person.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "collapse of the capacity" isn't widely used, but it seems to have found a home in the description of deficient *mental states*:

From [*The Matrix of the Mind: Object Relations and the Psychoanalytic Dialogue*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YAYHwU3JnuIC&pg=PA214&lpg=PA214&dq=%22collapse%20of%20the%20capacity%22&source=bl&ots=tx9ZQZrcjN&sig=F3U9bQJRenU9zteiwnZWI5fMjZI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizloS21ZDKAhVFKCYKHW8jDRwQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22collapse%20of%20the%20capacity%22&f=false) by Thomas Ogden (1992)

> ... I will attempt to begin to fill in that theory of the
>   psychopathology of symbolization by studying various forms of
>   incompleteness or **collapse of the capacity** *to maintain a
>   psychological dialectical process.*

From [*Dylan Thomas: The Code of Night*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rMFMAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA245&lpg=PA245&dq=%22collapse%20of%20the%20capacity%22&source=bl&ots=uAYwvLRPTQ&sig=5z29eeQ7F3S2XzRtHDfDmnGJnxM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizloS21ZDKAhVFKCYKHW8jDRwQ6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=%22collapse%20of%20the%20capacity%22&f=false) by David Holbrook (2014):

> His compulsive hedonism was in fact a manifestation of
>   'deterioration', marking the increasing **collapse of the capacity**
>   *to deal with reality*.

From ["The psychodynamic of panic attacks:
A useful integration of psychoanalysis and neuroscience"](http://philo.at/wiki/images/PanicDisorder.pdf) by Franco de Masi (International Journal of Psychoanalysis 2004;85:311–336)

> In the course of a panic crisis, a backache, diarrhoea, a praecordial
>   pain become elements followed by the **collapse of the capacity** for
>   *mental containment* and by the anxiety's flooding of the body.

Such examples can be multiplied several times over by searching the google with the (quoted) phrase, which also shows up occasionally to describe the failure of political, economic, or social systems.  Thus from ["Washington and The Contract With America"](http://www.theatlantic.com/past/docs/unbound/jfnpr/jfreview.htm) by James Fallows (*Atlantic Monthly*, 1994)

> That shift, to characterize it broadly, is the **collapse of the
>   capacity** of the *US economy* to sustain growth in jobs and income
>   for the middle class.

Other collapsed capacities include government regulation of water resources, appropriate police response to street protest, and the ability to collect taxes.

There is also a term of art in economics called the *capacity utilization rate* or *capacity utilization ratio*, obtained by dividing actual output by potential output.  It's claimed that an increasing ratio signals inflation while a decreasing ration signals recession.  I can find a [blog](https://thenextrecession.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/the-us-rate-of-the-profit-the-latest/) discussion in which the phrase "collapse of the capacity utilization ratios" occurs.

All of these uses are metaphorical, but they are all easy to understand from the meaning of a disastrous, incapacitating fall.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard it used as such, but theoretically, if you were talking about quantifiable production levels rather than an ability, you could.  That said, I'm not sure that you should.

The reason I think that you technically could is that production capacity, in a factory or industry for example, is often expressed as having lowered or fallen in order to mean that capacity decreased.  Semantically, if you can have a lowered capacity or a capacity that falls, then you can have a collapsed capacity.

Setting the theoretical aside for the practical, despite a BBA, an MBA, and 15 years in management, I've never heard anyone say "collapsed capacity," and I'm not at all sure that I'd readily understand what someone meant by it if I did here them use it.  Unless you're writing a book and/or trying to coin a specific phrase for your company or industry to describe a specific event or set of circumstances, I would advise you not use it.

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin. Could you possibly think of a better word to deliver this idea of an abrupt deterioration in a capacity to do something?

Comment: You haven't answered the question that @Andrew Leach and I put: By "capacity" do you mean a quantifiable volume, like complete loss of production capacity in a factory, or an ability, like someone no longer having the capacity to tie their own shoes? The verb you would use hinges greatly on which of these contexts you are asking about.

Comment: I meant capacity in the qualitative sense of 'ability' rather than in the quantitative sense.

Comment: If you are talking about in a qualitative sense, then capacities don't "fall" but are "lost."  For example, one might say, "John lost the capacity to tie his own shoes after he broke his arm," or, "After studying through the night, Mary lost any capacity to stay awake and so missed her test."

Comment: Interestingly, googling a few phrases indicates that while **capacities** collapse only rarely, **abilities** do collapse quite often. Is that true? Would it sound better to talk about the collapse of abilities?

Comment: @stultissimus: I've never heard anyone say, "abilities collapse," so I also Googled it. There were only 469 results on the whole web that put these words together. I found 466 of the 469 didn't really use "abilities" with "collapse" but simply had the two words next to each other, like in a list or where "abilities" ended one sentence and "collapse" started the next. Among Google's millions of searchable sites, there were only 3 that actually and oddly paired the noun "abilities" with the verb "collapse." So, no, it wouldn't be better to talk about the collapse of abilities. It makes no sense.